# does nouveau support hdmi for NV50 family video cards?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a GeForce G 105M. That's, I guess, an NV50 family video card:

https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/CodeNames/#NV50

My question is...  does [Nouveau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouveau_(software)) support HDMI with this video card?

According to https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/FeatureMatrix/ TVout is "TODO" and HDMI audio is "DONE". What about HDMI video? Is that grouped under TVout or is TVout supposed to be [S-Video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Video) support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this question is answered on nouveau@lists.freedesktop.org. The answer:

> TVout is in reference to Composite, S-Video, and (I think) Component
>   outputs.
>
> HDMI video is fully support on nv50-era GPUs. HDMI audio may be a bit
>   spotty depending on which GPU you have. (lspci -nn -d 10de: should
>   give you the info). Pre-GT215 GPUs have to get audio input via SPDIF
>   from the sound card, and nouveau doesn't quite configure that properly
>   - it might work, it might not. For GT215+ GPUs, HDMI audio should work fine.